# I used group by query to get desired output

Tags: c#, sql

This is my table(Tbl_12042014) with fields like recordId,batchName,SubaBatchname,OpStatus1,OpStatus2.

```
   RecordId     Batchname   SubBatchname     OpStatus1    OpStatus2
       1         12042014      raw3         D            D
       2         12042014      raw3         D            D
       3         12042014      raw4         Null         Null
       4         12042014      raw4         Null         Null
```

I used this query with group by but i didnt get desired output.
I want count recordId and column  which having Status 'D' for respective subbatchName.
fields with null value should be rejected.

**Query**

```
SELECT BatchName,SubBatchName,Count(RecordId)AS Records,
(Select count ( a.Opstatus1)  FROM  Tbl_12042014 as a where Opstatus1='D' ) as DE1,
(Select count(b.Opstatus2)  FROM  Tbl_12042014 as b where Opstatus2='D' )as DE2 
FROM  Tbl_12042014 GROUP BY BatchName, SubBatchName
```

I got  output  like by executing above query. I got DE1,DE2 count is 2 for raw3 and 2 for raw4.

```
Batchname   SubBatchname    Records DE1  DE2   
12042014    raw3               2     2    2   
12042014    raw4               2     2    2
```

But my desired output is like DE1,DE2 should be 2 for raw3 and 0 for raw4.

```
Batchname   SubBatchname    Records   DE1  DE2   
12042014    raw3              2        2    2     
12042014    raw4              2        0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with `case based aggregation`

```
SELECT BatchName,SubBatchName, Count(RecordId)AS Records,
sum(case when Opstatus1='D' then 1 else 0 end) as DE1,
sum(case when Opstatus2='D' then 1 else 0 end) as DE2 
FROM  Tbl_12042014 GROUP BY BatchName, SubBatchName
```